# Updating Ubuntu 18

Tags: boot, grub2

I have just installed ubuntu 18 iso from the web through USB memory stick on dual boot Win 10.
When booting Ubuntu 18. i have the screen flicketing beteeen no video black page and Ubuntu setup page. The system never stops looping.
I have put nomodeset quiet splash by editing e the grub. Then the system boot but does not recognise my password. 
I have login in safe mode to write nomodeset in the /etc/default/grubbut does not make any difference. 
Would you like to advise me?

Comment: If you `CTRL + ALT + F3` on the login screen, does it let you log in to the command line?

Comment: there is no "Ubuntu 16" release. 18.10 is EoL.